# Need help getting programmatic access to a Google Drive

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, windows-10

This might be a really basic question, but I can't quite figure out how to set up programmatic access to an external GD.

Our partner organization gives us access to their GD. I can access them through a browser. What I want to is to be able to programmatically download files from there (preferably using a python library) since there are a lot of them to download and I don't want to do it by hand.

I am using [**this**](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/quickstart.html) as a guide but got stuck at step 4 "click ‘Configure consent screen’ and follow the instructions" -- what am I supposed to specify as Application Name and other items? And is there a better/easier way to set up programmatic access?

In case it makes a difference:

- I am using a Win10 machine
- I have no admin rights on it

Any guidance will be much appreciated!

Comment: I believe this is the way google secure it's domains for programmatic accesses... Probably you should configure it with trusted information so you can use it properly.

Comment: can you explain what "Our partner organization gives us access to their GD" means?

Comment: @pinoyyid It means that they created multiple GDs, then I created a Google account with my email address and they gave me access to those drives with this account, giving me the ability to upload/download/etc. I can do all that from a browser but want to do it programmatically instead.

Comment: the "product name" is whatever you choose to call your app.
You could try following all of the steps at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention or look into creating a service account and ask your users to share their drives to the Service Account.